# How to insert file_name as value in each row of mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this structure in my trend_table, I'm uploading a csv file to mysql server. I want to insert my file_name into date_sourced for every rows. How can I put file name as values for my `date_sourced` column

**Example** `2018-10-02_trx_result.csv` is the name of my file  so `2018-10-02` should be put for every rows when I upload my csv

```
date_sourced : date
sha1: varchar(255)
vsdt: varchar(255)
trendx:varchar(255)
notes:varchar(255)
```

**PHP code** for uploading my CSV.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $host = 'localhost';
    $user = 'root';
    $password = '';
    $db = 'jeremy_db';
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 500);
    $con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password) or die('Could not' .mysqli_error($con));

    mysqli_select_db($con, $db) or die ('Could not' .mysqli_error($con));

    $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    ini_set ('memory_limit', filesize ($file) + 4000000);
    $c = 0;

    while(($csvdata = fgetcsv($handle,10000,","))!== FALSE){
        $sha1 = $csvdata[0];
        $vsdt = $csvdata[1];
        $trendx  = $csvdata[2];

        $sql = "INSERT INTO jeremy_table_trend (sha1,vsdt,trendx) VALUES ('$sha1','$vsdt','$trendx')";
        $query = mysqli_query($con , $sql);

        $c = $c+1;
    }
    if($query){
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
        echo '      alert("CSV uploaded to server");'; 
        echo '      window.location.href = "trendx.php";';
        echo '</script>';
    }
    else { 
        echo "SLAM";
    }
}
?>
```

**HTML code:**

```
<form id = "myForm" class="ui input" enctype="multipart/form-data" method = "POST" action="trend_upload_csv.php" role = "form">
     <input type = "file" name ="file" id="file" size = "150">
     <input id="myBtn"  class="ui small red button" type = "submit" class = "btn btn-default"  name ="submit" onclick = "myFunction();" value = "Upload CSV"  disabled  /> 
</form>
```

Please help me I have no idea for trimming file name and inserting file name to mysql :(

Comment: so what problem you are facing exactly?

Comment: how can I put file name as values for my date column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your filename is of the form `2018-10-02_trx_result.csv` (i.e. a date followed by `_` and the rest of the name), you can extract the date part using [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
list($date) = explode('_', $_FILES['file']['name']);
```

Then you can just edit your query to include the value of `$date`:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO jeremy_table_trend (date,sha1,vsdt,trendx) 
        VALUES ('$date','$sha1','$vsdt','$trendx')";
```

Note that you should really use prepared statements to guard against (for example) having data values with single quotes in them as well as other possible SQL injection attacks. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?s=1%7C1106.7827).

Comment: this gives me 0000-00-00 in my every rows

Comment: That sounds like your filename is not in the form you mention - or perhaps there is a path on it? What happens if you try `list($date) = explode('_', basename($_FILES['file']['name']));` Can you echo `$_FILES['file']['name']` to see what is in it?

Comment: (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

Comment: oh sorry my bad thanks! I was using other path i forgot :)

Comment: Good to see it's working - did you need the `basename`? If so I'll update the answer.

Comment: no need my friend, Thankyou very much! appreciated it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this,

```
$date = explode("_", !real filename here!)[0];
```

You can insert `$date` directly into your sql statement. Also make sure the date format in the file is always `YYYY-MM-DD`.